# Accept headers: application/rss+xml, text/rss+xml, text/xml

Tags: apache2, php, xml, rss

I have a Ubuntu with Apache and PHP running a web server and a full working web site on it. My problem is that recently I also added an API to it and the client fails with `'Error 406'`

My website responds with text/xml but it doesnt accept it. According to the developer of the client it must respond with the following headers: application/rss+xml, text/rss+xml, text/xml.

How do I fix/enable this on my server? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? Have you WireSharked the connection between the two yet?

Comment: Im using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Server Version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch
No I did use WireShark

Comment: What client?  Maybe someone else already has...

Comment: The client is nzbdrone and the error mentioned here: https://forums.sonarr.tv/t/http-status-406-returned-from-indexer/2440

Comment: So the additional API you installed on the server is `sabnzbplus`?

Comment: The API reply with available content to the client(the problem). The client will then send the request to sabnzbd. Everything works fine on sickbeard but doesnt with nzbdrone.

Comment: OK, I'm very sorry, but you've lost me now: no clue what you're talking about, so I can't help you any further...  :(

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by adding this to htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/xml .xml .php
</IfModule>
```

Not sure why it even works but it does